# SQL_ALCHEMY: Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

So for the piece of code that is causing this error:

```
long_url = Column(String(2043), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

I thought the max could be 3072 bytes, so I don't understand what's going wrong here.

The table itself:

```
from base import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Boolean, Integer


class URL(Base):
    __tablename__ = "urls"

    short_url = Column(String(256), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    long_url = Column(String(2043), nullable=False, unique=True)
    time = Column(String(256), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, short_url, long_url, time):
        self.short_url = short_url
        self.long_url = long_url
        self.time = time
```

Module `base.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from os import environ

load_dotenv()

root = environ.get("DB_USER")
password = environ.get("DB_PASSWORD")
port = environ.get("DB_PORT")
ip = environ.get("DB_IP")


engine = create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://{root}:{password}@{ip}:{port}/urldb".format(
        root=root, password=password, ip=ip, port=port
    )
)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @GordThompson I edited the question to include some more details

Comment: **what's going wrong here** -- Strings in Python are Unicode.  A 2043-character string is 4,086 bytes long.

Comment: @TimRoberts Never knew that. It makes so much more sense now.